# C file handling: Text doesn't append at the end of the file

Tags: c, file-handling

The program should look at each line of `file1` and then, see if the exact same line exists in `file2`. If it does, then copy the line to a new file named output.

Say, following are the content of files (It could be sentence but for simplicity, I've put numbers.)-

```
  file1              file2
    1                 2
    2                 4
    3                 15
    4                 6
    5                 11
    6                 8
    7
    8
    9
```

Then `output` file should look like -

```
 (Expected) output
              2
              4
              6
              8
```

Inside shell I can see printf prints `output` as expected, but fprintf inverts the order and I don't understand why? Output that gets printed to the output file is-

```
 output
    8
    6
    4
    2
```

Here's the code -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *file1, *file2, *output;
    int c;

    /*Creating buffers where data will be stored for comparison*/   
    char buffer1[999], buffer2[999];

    /*Settig the buffer characters array to 0*/
    memset(buffer1, 0, sizeof(buffer1));
    memset(buffer2, 0, sizeof(buffer2));

    /*Open output file in "w" so that it clears the file*/
    output = fopen("output", "w");
    /*Open file1 and then save the line inside buffer1 (within while loop)*/
    file1 = fopen("file1", "r");
    /*Read each character in file until End Of Line*/
    while((c = getc(file1)) != EOF)
    {
        int i = 0;
        /*Save each new line of file1 in buffer1 for comparison*/
        while(c != '\n')
        {
            buffer1[i++] = c;
            c = getc(file1);
        }

        /*Open file2 and then save it's line in buffer2 (withing while loop)*/      
        file2 = fopen("file2", "r");
        int ch;

        while((ch = getc(file2)) != EOF)
        {
            i = 0;
            while(ch != '\n')
            {
                buffer2[i++] = ch;
                ch = getc(file2);
            }

            /*Compare lines of file1 against each line of file2*/
            if(strcmp(buffer1,buffer2) == 0)
            {
                /*Save similar lines in a file named output*/
                output = fopen("output", "a");
                fprintf(output,"%s\n", buffer2);
                printf("%s\n", buffer2);
                break;
            }
            /*Reset the buffer*/
            memset(buffer2, 0, sizeof(buffer2));
        }

        memset(buffer1, 0, sizeof(buffer1));
    }

    /*Close the output file if there were any comparison made i.e. if file was opened*/
    if(output != NULL)
    {
        fclose(output);
    }

    /*Close other files*/
    fclose(file1);
    fclose(file2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: PS: I'm beginner at this and still not sure if I write the code properly, please be kind :)
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are *opening* `output` *at each difference* and closing *just one time at the end* this is wrong and maybe causing your problem. Try to open `output` once, maybe before the loop. You can remove it if you dont find any difference, to avoid an empty file.

Comment: This is it, thanks so much. I couldn't have figured it out on my own, it's not so obvious to me that I need to close it every time. BTW, looking at it now, I feel like it's not the most elegant way of doing it (Open/close for writing each line.) Do you think there could be a better way to deal with it?

Comment: @GuravButola is betetr if you open and close once, no reason to open each time before to write :) so open at the beginning, write whenever you want, and close at the end.

Comment: Oh Well! this seems to work, and gives output, but gives some error at I run it. http://pastebin.com/s8SLD8PM

Comment: @GauravButola does not seems file related, some poiter apper to be corrupted

Comment: Any idea why this doesn't seem to work at all under Windows? It straightaway crashes. I am not using anything Linux specific AFAICT; Or should I ask this o a different question?